# Is there a way to broadcast UDP packets with ESP8266 without wifi connection?

Tags: networking, arduino, udp, broadcast, esp8266

My question is regarding an ESP8266 board and the ESP-touch technology.

ESP-touch uses the length field of a UDP package to broadcast wifi ID and PW through a device (like a smartphone) to the chip (like in my case ESP 8266).

I want to turn this around, more specifically:
I want the ESP8266 chip to broadcast UDP packets with some sort of identifier-number in the length field of the UDP packet, without beeing connected to any wifi connection. Then these UDP packets are recieved by an app on a smartphone so the identifier-number can be extracted and used on the smartphone.

I am relatively new to this topic and do not know if this can work.

When I try to find any information online they all say that the first step is to connect the chip to a wifi. But I don't want that. The smartphone and the chip don't know each other and are not connected in any way. So I want this type of "broadcasting" so that the smartphone can recieve the package without really beeing connected to the chip.

I guess there must be some way to make it function like I explained above, but I can't find a way how this can work.

I don't need the chip to send UDP packets explicitely, it can be any type of package. I took UDP packet as an example because there is already the ESP-touch technology which is more or less similar.

The important thing is that the package that I send has a field where I can put some identifier-number in (not encrypted), which can then be recieved by  another device like a smartphone where this identifier-number is extracted.

For clarification: I don't need to use ESP touch or anything related to that. I only stated this technology as an example. I just want to achieve the behavior stated above and in the picture! :)

This is an example picture how I want it to work:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible to send any packages without being connected to the network. ESP-touch or [TI Smart Config](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61704/how-does-ti-cc3000-wifi-smart-config-work) or similar technologies utilize [Monitor mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode). As the name suggests, in this mode one can listen for packages, but can't send them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But as I stated above I don't need to use ESP-touch or anything related to that. I just stated that as an similar example. I just want to achieve the explained behavior (see the picture)
Is there a way to achieve that with some other technology/library or something else ?

Comment: I am not aware of any 802.11 standard modes which would allow sending data without being connected. So at least with WiFi it is not possible (and ESP8266 doesn't have other wireless communication interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

ESPNOW provides data flow between ESP devices without connections via router. It is another feature of the Espressive API. There are tutorials for ESP8266 and ESP32...
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp-now-esp8266-nodemcu-arduino-ide/  .. https://www.instructables.com/ESP32-With-ESP-Now-Protocol/